# clicking on cell to select/de-select checkbox

Tags: html, angularjs

I have checkboxes like this:

[image]

If I click on the words 'Awaiting first meeting', it selects and de-selects the checkbox.  If I click on the cell (e.g., the black portion, but not on the text itself), it does not select/de-select the checkbox.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="option in item.options">
        <td>
            <input id="{{ item.id }}-{{ $index }}"
                   type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td ng-style="{'backgroundColor':option.color}">
            <label for="{{ item.id }}-{{ $index }}" ng-style="{'backgroundColor': option.color}">{{ option.title }}</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

One thing I tried is to make label width equal to 100% of the cell, but if the text is blank, this won't work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to either change your markup

```
<label ng-repeat="option in item.options" ng-style="{'backgroundColor':option.color}">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ option.title }}"/>{{ option.title }}
</label>
```

Or you add `ng-checked` and `ng-click`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in item.options">
    <td>
        <input ng-checked="item.checked" type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
    <td ng-style="{'backgroundColor':option.color}">
        <label ng-click="item.checked = !item.checked"  ng-style="{'backgroundColor': option.color}">
            {{ option.title }}
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```